# HTTP Status 500 error

Tags: java, tomcat, jsp-tags

I'm getting the error like

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.sixpanview.getcoordinate resolves to a package
An error occurred at line: 7 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.sixpanview.fileReader resolves to a package
An error occurred at line: 8 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.sixpanview.cookieInfo resolves to a package
```

and getting errors at the lines which uses `getcoordinate`, `fileReader` and `cookieInfo` in the .jsp program and the stack trace is

```
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Why am i getting it?

Comment: You should provide the jsp file also, or at least the mentioned lines.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import a `package`. You need to import `classes` inside that package.

In your import statement, replace your imports with: -

```
com.sixpanview.getcoordinate.*;
com.sixpanview.fileReader.*;
com.sixpanview.cookieInfo.*;
```

I assume there is not other sub-package under those packages.

`.*` will import all the classes under that package. Ideally, you should not do that. Rather `import` a specific class from those package if you know what are they.

Like: -

```
import java.util.List;
```

is better than: -

```
import java.util.*;
```

**P.S : -** Please don't use `bold case` in your content, unless it is really really important to be highlighted. Its difficult to read. And also post your code snippet in future, while posting exceptions.